# remove items from specific place on the list

Tags: python

I want to remove some items from specific places. for example, I have list `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]`. the number of items in this list constantly changes.

That is why I need special method that is helps to remove items from same place. Now the modified list should be like that: list `[a,b,c,d,e,f,i]`. `g` and `h` should always be removed.

Comment: What is the other input ? What decide to remove the g and h ?

Comment: The script is so long that is why i didnt add here. There is function that returns list[] and i need to change some item inside it.

Comment: how do you decide which item to change/remove ?

Comment: `l.remove(g)` ?

Comment: What is the criteria for removal? Is it the position or the values "g" and "h". What if those values/positions don't exist. Be specific.

Comment: I don't want the script, I want the rules, why **that specific** values

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to remove the second- and third-last item from the list?

This can be achieved like this:

```
del lst[-3:-1]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know if "second-last" is a term, lol

Comment: this solution is what i want thank you guys

Comment: please mark question as answered, thanks :)

Comment: I am new in this platform. could you please help me find to find a button to mark your post as answered?

Answer (score 0):

If you create dictionaries with necessary indexes you can use them to create a new list.

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

other = ['a','y','b','c','d','e','g','h','l']

indexed_lst = {i: item for i, item in enumerate(lst)}

indexed_other = {i: item for i, item in enumerate(other)}

[item for i, item in indexed_lst.items() if indexed_lst.get(i, None) !=  indexed_other.get(i, None) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove from the list either `by index` or `by value`. In either case it is a good practice to `check if the index/value is present in the list`. As for removing an item from the list you could use one of the below based on what info is available / output required.

***Remove an item by index and get its value: pop()***

```
# where i is the index of the value to be removed
if i < len(lst)
    result = l.pop(i)
```

***Remove items by index or slice: del()***

```
# where i is the index of the value to be removed
if i < len(lst) :
    lst.del(i)
```

***Remove an item by value: remove()***

```
# where `h` is the value to be removed
if 'h' in lst:
    lst.remove('h')
```

You could also remove items from a list based on a given condition, in which case you could use `list comprehensions`

```
l = list(range(10))
# Remove all the odd numbers
print([i for i in l if i % 2 != 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

ahh i understand your answer, if you use index like this

**Remove items by index, specific place**

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
lst = [item for index,item in enumerate(lst) if index != 6 and index != 7]
print(lst)
```

or **Remove items by Value**

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
lst = [item for item in lst if item != 'g' and item != 'h']
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .pop() to pop off any given index off the list

Answer (score -1):

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
lst = [item for item in lst if item != 'g' and item != 'h']
print(lst)
```

if you have more input, tell me

Comment: Seonghun, your solution is greate. But one more think i wnat to mention. imagine the list is like that: lst=[33,25,43,65,87,12,43,54] and the item inside it constantly changes. Is there any why that we can find items by its place not by its name? for instance, remove fifth and sixth items

Comment: i understand it i add answer